# Handling Null Values in ADF Pipeline

Tags: null, azure-data-factory, coalesce, isnull, incremental-load

I am performing an incremental load using timestamp as watermark column. I have few null values in the date column in my source. When I am replicating the data using copy activity, only rows whose date column is not null are getting copied, but I want to copy all other rows too where date column has null values.

I have tried using IsNull and Coalesce in the lookup activites but that does not work . is there a way where I can handle those null values in ADF

Comment: What is the replacement value you use in IsNull or Coalesce function?

Comment: @Aswin I am using the 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 , so if i get null value from my date column it should replace it will the above value

Comment: your max watermark value in the previous run will be greater than '1900-01-01'

Comment: Try to replace the null value with max watermark value in the source data.

Comment: @Aswin I am using select 
coalesce(MAX(@{item().WaterMark_Column}),'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000')
as NewWatermarkvalue from @{item().TABLE_NAME}  in my lookup and its taking that value where date us null , even the pipeline succeeds but the row is not getting copied over and there is only 1 record in this table

Comment: Why are replacing in lookup table? Replace the null value in source table with max watermark date value of previous pipeline run.

Comment: @Aswin one more thing, if I dont want to replace the null value but I want that record in my target because only date is null but rest of the columns are not null . I have this query in my copy activity, somehow this is ignoring the rows with null dates.                                   select * from @{item().TABLE_NAME} where 
(@{item().WaterMark_Column} >= '@{activity('Oldwatermark').output.firstRow.WatermarkValue}' 
and @{item().WaterMark_Column} <= '@{activity('Newwatermark').output.firstRow.NewWatermarkvalue}')
or (@{item().WaterMark_Column}= null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not replacing null watermark values in source table and copying the data as is, it is not incremental load. For every pipeline run, same rows with null value will be copied. If null values data can be copied in every run, you can use the same query. In that query, change `(@{item().WaterMark_Column}= null)` as `(@{item().WaterMark_Column} is null)` .

**Corrected Code:**

```sql
select * from @{item().TABLE_NAME} where 
(@{item().WaterMark_Column} >= '@{activity('Oldwatermark').output.firstRow.WatermarkValue}'and
@{item().WaterMark_Column} <= '@{activity('Newwatermark').output.firstRow.NewWatermarkvalue}') 
or (@{item().WaterMark_Column} is null)
```

Reference: **MS document** on [IS NULL or IS NOT NULL instead of comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks)

Comment: ah okay, Thank you so much for clearing somethings, It was a bit confusing while working on ADF or I must have overthought and made it confusing